# vidas juego de palabras c++

Tags: c++

Tengo mi código, pero no se como hacer que el juego acabe cuando vidas llegue a 0, bueno no se como meterlo, porque ya intente pero no se reduce, y no se como hacer que el el juego acabe cuando las vidas se reduzcan a 0, pero no bajan las vidas que es la variable ups=5; solamente es eso, quisiera saber si debo implementar otra función o algo, tenia una función llamada, vidas pero no sabia como hacer para que se pudieran reducir las vidas en base a lo que otra función hacia.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char a[4]={'h','o','l','a'};
char b[4];
void juego(char,bool,int);

void mostrar();
void terminar();
int main() {
    int n=1;
    char letra;
    bool existe=false;
    int ups=5;
    cout << "****Juego del ahorcado****" << endl;
    do {
        cout<<endl;
        cout << "Digite una letra para adivinar" << endl;
        cin >> letra;

        juego(letra, existe, ups);
        mostrar();

        terminar();
    }while(n!=0);

}
void juego(char letra, bool existe, int ups){

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (a[i] == letra) {
            existe = true;
            b[i] = a[i];
        }

        }


    if(existe==false){
        ups-1;
        cout<<"Vidas restantes"<<ups<<endl;
    }

        if (existe) {
            cout << "correcto " << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "fallaste" << endl;
        }


    }





void mostrar(){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[i]){
            cout<<"*";
        }
        if(a[i]==b[i]) {
            cout << b[i];
        }
    }
    }
void terminar() {

        if (a[3] == b[3]) {
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Juego terminado";
            exit(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: para decrementar la variable ups no es `ups-1;`, lo puedes hacer de las siguientes formas `ups = ups -1;`, `ups -= 1;`, `ups--;` o `--ups;`

Comment: ya lo intente pero no me sale de igual forma

Comment: Debes de volver a estructurar la lógica de tu programa porque si la primer letra que ingreso es "a" el juego termina

Comment: lo acabo de corregir

Comment: pero aun tengo problema con lo de las vidas u_u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como estás declarando la función:

```
void juego(char letra, bool existe, int ups){
```

Estás haciendo una copia de cada parámetro:

```
void juego(char letra, bool existe, int ups){
//         ~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~
//            copia       copia      copia
```

Al hacer una copia creas una variable nueva, diferente de la original, que hereda el valor que tenía la variable inicial. Los cambios que se realizan en la copia no afectan a la variable original, de la misma forma que si te creases un clon, entonces el clon podría teñirse el pelo sin que el tuyo cambiase de color mágicamente.

Bien, tu lo que buscas es que, al menos `ups` sea una referencia:

```
void juego(char letra, bool existe, int & ups){
```

Ahora no se creará una copia de la variable `ups` original, sino que ambas variables estarán vinculadas, de tal forma que los cambios que realices a `ups` dentro de `juego`  afectarán a la variable `ups` que has declarado en el `main`

Comment: al agregar el & me dice ahora que la función juego nunca se utilizo, a que se debe?

Comment: @Xetine A que esa función tiene, además de la implementación, una declaración en la línea 5 de tu programa. Si cambias la firma de la implementación debes modificar también la declaración para que coincidan: `void juego(char, bool, int&);`

Comment: eres grande, muchas gracias!